# How to inject an object from a classic MVC controller method to a RazorPage

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, razor-pages

I've done quite a few projects using the classic MVC controllers and views, but would like to try out the new RazorPages. The app I'm working on is a dotnetcore with a classic MVC controller in it and I need to add a single view page to the app.

I would like to receive a POST on an MVC controller method, but "redirect" the Model object I have received so that is can be consumed by a new RazorPage.

What is my best option here to initialize the RazorPage with this object? (I have to leave the old MVC controller/routes in place for other reasons).

Comment: So you want to have your post form in an MVC View and when you submit the form a Razor Page will receive the contents of the form?

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear. I want to receive a POST on an MVC controller (JSON), then use the serialized object from that post as the model for a RazorPage. Just very unclear how to mix/match MVC classic and RazorPages.